# SailsJS simple authentication not working

Tags: authentication, sails.js

sorry for my noob question im only a 1day old sails user. I need a really simple authentication for SailsJS where I can login by giving an email/username and a password. I managed to create a part where I can sign up and login succesfully but I don't know how to persist the authentication through out the app for other requests.

I have written the controllers that needs authentication in config/policies.js

```
SubjectController: {
 '*': ['sessionAuth']
},
GradeController: {
  '*': ['sessionAuth']
}
```

After I log in I give back the session in the callback

```
  req.session.me = user.id;
  if (req.wantsJSON) {
    return res.ok(req.session);
  }
```

But after that I don't have a clue on what to store what the sailsjs gives back to me.. and what to send with the next request in order to show that I am authenticated?

I know I can use services like passport etc but I think thats too big for what I want since its a small little project here what I am creating.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to persist your session somewhere (I generally use REDIS):
http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/sessions

I generally use Passport for the authentication side:
http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/policies/sails-passport